# What's the main difference between int.Parse() and Convert.ToInt32

Tags: c#

- What is the main difference between `int.Parse()` and `Convert.ToInt32()`?
- Which one is to be preferred

Answer (score 517, accepted):

- If you've got a string, and you expect it to always be an integer (say, if some web service is handing you an integer in string format), you'd use [**`Int32.Parse()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx).
- If you're collecting input from a user, you'd generally use [**`Int32.TryParse()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx), since it allows you more fine-grained control over the situation when the user enters invalid input.
- [**`Convert.ToInt32()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert.ToInt32.aspx) takes an object as its argument.  (See Chris S's answer for how it works)

  `Convert.ToInt32()` also does not throw `ArgumentNullException` when its argument is null the way `Int32.Parse()` does. That also means that `Convert.ToInt32()` is probably a wee bit slower than `Int32.Parse()`, though in practice, unless you're doing a very large number of iterations in a loop, you'll never notice it.

Comment: As others point out, Convert.ToInt32(s) doesn't throw an exception when s is null, but Parse() does. "A bit slower" is completely beside the point as you'll never measure the difference.

Comment: Thanks, Robert!  I'm editing my answer for some more completeness.  But as far as performance goes, I'll bet the difference in speed would be detectable if you're calling it in a nested loop...

Comment: Actually, since the `ToInt32` method has an overload for loads of types, there among them `System.String`, no time will be lost discerning the type. The actual code does nothing but return 0 for null values, and `int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` for everything else.

Comment: Where does it say in the documentation that Convert.ToInt32(s) doesn't throw an exception when s is null?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @StealthRabbi: In the "Return value" section of the documentation: *"A 32-bit signed integer that is equivalent to the number in value, or 0 (zero) if value is null."*

Comment: please remove your mention of `Int32.TryParse()` in `Convert.ToInt32()` because it is incorrect. Convert throws an exception if the string is formatted incorrectly.

Comment: I second Dehalion's comment "please remove your mention of Int32.TryParse() in Convert.ToInt32() because it is incorrect"

Comment: @Dehalion I never said that it didn't, just that TryParse() gets called inside Convert.ToInt32().  I never meant to imply that these functions had the same functionality.  Edited to refer to Chris's answer.

Answer (score 222):

Have a look in reflector:

**int.Parse("32"):**

```
public static int Parse(string s)
{
    return System.Number.ParseInt32(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}
```

which is a call to:

```
internal static unsafe int ParseInt32(string s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
{
    byte* stackBuffer = stackalloc byte[1 * 0x72];
    NumberBuffer number = new NumberBuffer(stackBuffer);
    int num = 0;
    StringToNumber(s, style, ref number, info, false);
    if ((style & NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) != NumberStyles.None)
    {
        if (!HexNumberToInt32(ref number, ref num))
        {
            throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32"));
        }
        return num;
    }
    if (!NumberToInt32(ref number, ref num))
    {
        throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32"));
    }
    return num;
}
```

**Convert.ToInt32("32"):**

```
public static int ToInt32(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

As the first (Dave M's) comment says.

Comment: Thanks for removing all the conjecture from the prior answer.

Comment: shouldn't it be "return default(int);" ?

Comment: In short, `Convert.ToInt32` returns `0` if `null` to prevent `int.Parse` from raising an `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek - The expression `default(int)` is evaluated at compile time, since its an intrinsic value - the result of the expression is `0`, so the compiler inserts a literal `0`. The IL disassembly tools can't know any better, so they just show you a literal zero.

Comment: @antiduh: You are right, but in the terms of defensive programming I would still prefere "default(int)". What if, hypothetically, the value of default(int) change?

Comment: It can't change - the result of that expression is hardcoded in .net binaries everywhere, and there are probably countless places where code is checking for a value that derived from default(int) (eg, checking to see if a class member variable has been changed from 0). In order to effect a change to the value of `default(int)` every drop of .Net code in the world would have to be recompiled, or nobody's programs would work.

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek This is entirely besides the point. The user was copying reflected code. To change it would be an incorrect representation of what is compiled. If the user had original source and the original source had default(int) then that is what the user would have posted.

Comment: @rshadman True, I did not realised it was code from Reflector.

Comment: I'm a little late but it is impossible for the meaning of `default(int)` to change since the [default value expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions) always returns zero (i.e. all the bits of the returned struct are zero) for value types, including user-defined structs and null for reference types. You can also safely return false for booleans instead of `default(bool)`, for example. It would be very, very strange to represent the zero value for a numeric type using non-zero bits.

Comment: Why this fact-based answer didn't get more love over the years is a mystery to me especially considering it was written within a day of the accepted answer

Answer (score 97):

No difference as such.
`Convert.ToInt32()` calls `int.Parse()` internally

Except for one thing `Convert.ToInt32()` returns `0` when argument is `null`

Otherwise both work the same way

Comment: More precisely, `Convert.ToInt32(string)` calls `int.Parse` internally. `Convert.ToInt32(object)`, however, calls `((IConvertible) value).ToInt32`, which in the case of `string` calls `Convert.ToInt32(string)`... a bit convoluted...

Comment: Yeah, Convert.ToInt32(char) will actually return (int)value, which will turn '1' into 49.  Not generally the intended functionality.

Answer (score 49):

## int.Parse(string s)

- Integer in RANGE                  > returns integer value
- Null value                        > ArguementNullException
- Not in format                     > FormatException
- Value not in RANGE                > OverflowException

## Convert.ToInt32(string s)

- Integer in RANGE                  > returns integer value
- Null value                        > returns "0"
- Not in format                     > FormatException
- Value not in RANGE                > OverflowException

## bool isParsed = int.TryParse(string s,out res)

- Integer in RANGE                  > returns integer value, isParsed = true
- Null value                        > returns "0", isParsed = false
- Not in format                     > returns "0", isParsed = false
- Value not in RANGE                > returns "0", isParsed = false

Try this code below.....

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strInt = "24532";
        string strNull = null;
        string strWrongFrmt = "5.87";
        string strAboveRange = "98765432123456";
        int res;
        try
        {
            // int.Parse() - TEST
            res = int.Parse(strInt); // res = 24532
            res = int.Parse(strNull); // System.ArgumentNullException
            res = int.Parse(strWrongFrmt); // System.FormatException
            res = int.Parse(strAboveRange); // System.OverflowException

            // Convert.ToInt32(string s) - TEST
            res = Convert.ToInt32(strInt); // res = 24532
            res = Convert.ToInt32(strNull); // res = 0
            res = Convert.ToInt32(strWrongFrmt); // System.FormatException
            res = Convert.ToInt32(strAboveRange); //System.OverflowException

            // int.TryParse(string s, out res) - Test
            bool isParsed;
            isParsed = int.TryParse(strInt, out res); // isParsed = true, res = 24532
            isParsed = int.TryParse(strNull, out res); // isParsed = false, res = 0
            isParsed = int.TryParse(strWrongFrmt, out res); // isParsed = false, res = 0
            isParsed = int.TryParse(strAboveRange, out res); // isParsed = false, res = 0 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Check this.\n" + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ref: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32885/Difference-Between-Int-Parse-Convert-ToInt-and

Comment: very useful summary , thanks!

Answer (score 25):

The difference is this:

`Int32.Parse()` and `Int32.TryParse()` can only convert strings. `Convert.ToInt32()` can take any class that implements `IConvertible`. If you pass it a string, then they are equivalent, except that you get extra overhead for type comparisons, etc. If you are converting strings, then `TryParse()` is probably the better option.

Answer (score 14):

**Int32.parse(string)--->**

Int32.Parse (string s) method converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. When s is a null reference, it will throw ArgumentNullException. If s is other than integer value, it will throw FormatException. When s represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue, it will throw OverflowException. ***For example***:

```
string s1 = "1234"; 
string s2 = "1234.65"; 
string s3 = null; 
string s4 = "123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789"; 

result = Int32.Parse(s1);    //1234
result = Int32.Parse(s2);    //FormatException
result = Int32.Parse(s3);    //ArgumentNullException 
result = Int32.Parse(s4);    //OverflowException
```

**Convert.ToInt32(string) -->**
Convert.ToInt32(string s) method converts the specified string representation of 32-bit signed integer equivalent. This calls in turn Int32.Parse () method. When s is a null reference, it will return 0 rather than throw ArgumentNullException. If s is other than integer value, it will throw FormatException. When s represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue, it will throw OverflowException.

***For example:***

```
 result = Convert.ToInt32(s1);    // 1234 
 result = Convert.ToInt32(s2);    // FormatException
 result = Convert.ToInt32(s3);    // 0
 result = Convert.ToInt32(s4);    // OverflowException
```

Comment: add reference: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32885/Difference-Between-Int-Parse-Convert-ToInt-and

Answer (score 11):

TryParse is faster...

> The first of these functions, Parse, is one that should be familiar to
>   any .Net developer. This function will take a string and attempt to
>   extract an integer out of it and then return the integer. If it runs
>   into something that it can’t parse then it throws a FormatException or
>   if the number is too large an OverflowException. Also, it can throw an
>   ArgumentException if you pass it a null value.
>
> TryParse is a new addition to the new .Net 2.0 framework that addresses some issues with the original Parse function. The main
>   difference is that exception handling is very slow, so if TryParse is
>   unable to parse the string it does not throw an exception like Parse
>   does. Instead, it returns a Boolean indicating if it was able to
>   successfully parse a number. So you have to pass into TryParse both
>   the string to be parsed and an Int32 out parameter to fill in. We will
>   use the profiler to examine the speed difference between TryParse and
>   Parse in both cases where the string can be correctly parsed and in
>   cases where the string cannot be correctly parsed.
>
> The Convert class contains a series of functions to convert one base class into another. I believe that
>   Convert.ToInt32(string) just checks for a null string (if the string
>   is null it returns zero unlike the Parse) then just calls
>   Int32.Parse(string). I’ll use the profiler to confirm this and to see
>   if using Convert as opposed to Parse has any real effect on
>   performance.

[Source with examples](http://blogs.msdn.com/ianhu/archive/2005/12/19/505702.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: When you look at the source from TryParse it actually has no exception handling at all - just character manipulation and bit shifting, thanks for the link

Comment: [According to these benchmarks](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int), Parse, TryParse, and Convert are pretty much the same speed unless you're converting more than 2 million objects.

Answer (score 5):

```
Convert.ToInt32
```

has 19 overloads or 19 different ways that you can call it. Maybe more in 2010 versions.

It will attempt to convert from the following TYPES;

> > Object, Boolean, Char, SByte, Byte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, Single, Double, Decimal, String, Date

and it also has a number of other methods; one to do with a number base and 2 methods involve a `System.IFormatProvider`

Parse on the other hand only has 4 overloads or 4 different ways you can call the method.

```
Integer.Parse( s As String)

Integer.Parse( s As String,  style As System.Globalization.NumberStyles )

Integer.Parse( s As String, provider As System.IFormatProvider )

Integer.Parse( s As String,  style As System.Globalization.NumberStyles, provider As System.IFormatProvider )
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a detail for `int.Parse` and `Convert.ToInt32`:
Say, you have a char array, `char[] a=['1','2','3','4']` and want to convert each element into an integer.
The `Convert.ToInt32(a[0])` will give you a number of 49. It treats it as ASCII code
The `int.Parse(a[0])` will give you the right output which is 1

If you have a string array `string[] b=['1','2','3','4']`, then `Convert.ToInt32` and `int.Parse` will have no difference in output. Both return the right integer.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the parameter type.  For example, I just discovered today that it will convert a char directly to int using its ASCII value.  Not exactly the functionality I intended...

YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED!

```
public static int ToInt32(char value)
{
    return (int)value;
} 

Convert.ToInt32('1'); // Returns 49
int.Parse('1'); // Returns 1
```

Comment: Can `char` convert implicitly to `string` in C#?  It certainly can in VB.NET, and so programmers in that language would likely expect `Convert.ToInt32("1"c)` and `Convert.ToInt32("1")` to be equivalent, but I don't think C# has that implicit conversion.

Comment: You cannot convert char to string, either implicitly or explicitly.  You would need to call '1'.ToString() or new string('1', 1);

Comment: I wouldn't consider the "warning" terribly significant for C#, since that language regards `char` values as being a bit more number-ish than vb.net.  The danger would be greater in vb.net, where there because of an implicit cast there's less of a perceived difference between `Char` and `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Convert.ToInt32 allows null value, it doesn't throw any errors
Int.parse does not allow null value, it throws an ArgumentNullException error.

Answer (score 2):

Parse() methods provide the number styles which cannot be used for Convert(). For example:

```
int i;
bool b = int.TryParse( "123-",
           System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign,
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
           out i);
```

would parse the numbers with trailing sign so that i == -123
The trailing sign is popular in ERP systems.

Answer (score 1):

for clarification open console application, just copy below code and paste it in  `static void Main(string[] args)` method, I hope you can  understand

```
public  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            int result;
            bool status;
            string s1 = "12345";
            Console.WriteLine("input1:12345");
            string s2 = "1234.45";
            Console.WriteLine("input2:1234.45");
            string s3 = null;
            Console.WriteLine("input3:null");
            string s4 = "1234567899012345677890123456789012345667890";
            Console.WriteLine("input4:1234567899012345677890123456789012345667890");
            string s5 = string.Empty;
            Console.WriteLine("input5:String.Empty");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("--------Int.Parse Methods Outputs-------------");
            try
            {
               result = int.Parse(s1);

               Console.WriteLine("OutPut1:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut1:"+ee.Message);
            }
            try
            {
              result = int.Parse(s2);

              Console.WriteLine("OutPut2:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut2:" + ee.Message);
            }
            try
            {
               result = int.Parse(s3);

               Console.WriteLine("OutPut3:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut3:" + ee.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                result = int.Parse(s4);

                Console.WriteLine("OutPut4:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut4:" + ee.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                 result = int.Parse(s5);

                 Console.WriteLine("OutPut5:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut5:" + ee.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("--------Convert.To.Int32 Method Outputs-------------");
            try
            {

                result=  Convert.ToInt32(s1);

                Console.WriteLine("OutPut1:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut1:" + ee.Message);
            }
            try
            {

                result = Convert.ToInt32(s2);

                Console.WriteLine("OutPut2:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut2:" + ee.Message);
            }
            try
            {

         result = Convert.ToInt32(s3);

         Console.WriteLine("OutPut3:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut3:" + ee.Message);
            }
            try
            {

                  result = Convert.ToInt32(s4);

                  Console.WriteLine("OutPut4:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut4:" + ee.Message);
            }

            try
            {

                 result = Convert.ToInt32(s5);

                 Console.WriteLine("OutPut5:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut5:" + ee.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("--------TryParse Methods Outputs-------------");
            try
            {

                status = int.TryParse(s1, out result);
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut1:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut1:" + ee.Message);
            }
            try
            {

                status = int.TryParse(s2, out result);
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut2:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut2:" + ee.Message);
            }
            try
            {

                status = int.TryParse(s3, out result);
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut3:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut3:" + ee.Message);
            }
            try
            {

                status = int.TryParse(s4, out result);
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut4:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut4:" + ee.Message);
            }

            try
            {

                status = int.TryParse(s5, out result);
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut5:" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OutPut5:" + ee.Message);
            }


            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One niche but significant difference not covered in the currently accepted answer is that Entity Framework does not, at least currently, support `int.Parse()` but does support `Convert.Int32()` for LINQ to SQL, for some reason.

Presumably this wasn't relevant to the person that posed the question originally, considering EF had only just released back in 2008. Still, tossing that in since this does come up as a top search result and is the reason I wound up here.