# Difference between converting strings

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between Convert.tostring() and .tostring()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828154/difference-between-convert-tostring-and-tostring)

Hi

Carrying on from this question [What is the difference between Convert and Parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486810/the-difference-between-convert-and-parse)

Here are two lines of code.

```
Convert.ToString(myObject);
myObject.ToString();
```

My question is what is the difference and which would be best to use?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic difference between them is `Convert` function handles `NULL`s while `i.ToString()`
does not.  It will throw a `NULL` reference exception error.  So, as good coding practice using
`Convert` is always safe.

Comment: Just to clarify - Convert.ToString(null) would return null?

Comment: @Ash, yes it returns null although one might reasonably expect it to return the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

`myObject.ToString()` could throw a `NullReferenceException`, where `Convert.ToString` will never do that.