# Any difference between DateTime.Parse and Convert.ToDateTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Is there any difference between

```
Convert.ToDateTime
```

and

```
DateTime.Parse
```

Which one is faster or which is more secure to use?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486810/what-is-the-difference-between-convert-and-parse

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Per an [answer on another forum from Jon Skeet](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/482419-convert-todatetime-vs-system-datetime-parse)...

> Convert.ToDateTime uses DateTime.Parse internally, with the current 
>   culture - unless you pass it null, in which case it returns 
>   DateTime.MinValue.

If you're not sure string is a valid `DateTime`, use neither and instead, use `DateTime.TryParse()`

If you're sure the string is a valid `DateTime`, and you know the format, you could also consider the `DateTime.ParseExact()` or `DateTime.TryParseExact()` methods.

Comment: "In short, Convert.ToDateTime() eliminates the code necessary to set the CultureInfo, which you'd have to do to use DateTime.Parse()"
That's not true. You donn't have to set the CultureInfo to use DateTime.Parse(). DateTime.Parse has an overload that takes only 1 string and nothing else and it uses the current culture info without you having to pass it in.

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime.Parse` will throw an `Exception` when a null string is passed, `Convert.ToDateTime` will return `DateTime.MinValue` on passing a null value.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.Parse` has an overload that takes only one `String` and nothing else and it uses the current `Locale` info without you having to pass it in.

Answer (score 1):

The overloads of Convert.ToDateTime which take string as input parameter, internally invoked DateTime.Parse. Following is the implementation of Convert.ToDateTime.

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return new DateTime(0L);
    }
    return DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

In case of other overload, the parameter is casted into IConvertible interface and then the corresponding ToDateTime method is invoked.

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(ushort value)
{
    return ((IConvertible) value).ToDateTime(null);
}
```