# Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
below is the stack trace-

> "   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi,
>   DateTimeStyles styles)\r\n   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String
>   value)\r\n   at
>   ConsoleApplication10.Program.b_*1(<>f*_AnonymousType0`1 a) in
>   C:\\Documents and Settings\\xxxxdev\\My Documents\\Visual Studio
>   2008\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication10\\ConsoleApplication10\\Program.cs:line
>   23\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at
>   ConsoleApplication10.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\hj81dev\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10\Program.cs:line
>   28\r\n   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly,
>   String[] args)\r\n   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()\r\n 
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)\r\n
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()"

this is my code. in the sql server database my dateofbirth field is varbinary type

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var customerProfileGuid = new Guid("35D02589-C5FA-437D-B661-000215C68584");
            using (CustomerProfileEntities context = new CustomerProfileEntities())
            {
                var test = from x in context.CustomerProfile
                           where x.CustomerProfileId == customerProfileGuid
                           select new { x };

                var customerData = test.ToList();
                var customerResult = (from a in customerData
                                      select new Profile
                                      {
                                          DateOfBirth =Convert.ToDateTime(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(a.x.DateOfBirth)) //getting error here
                                      });

                foreach (var profile in customerResult)
                {
                    var profileData = profile;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    public class Profile
    {
        private DateTime dateOfBirthField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dateOfBirthField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dateOfBirthField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please do the needful

Comment: What value are you trying to pass in for a date?

Comment: Have you checked what Encoding.UTF8.GetString(a.x.DateOfBirth) actually returns?

Comment: Breakpoint that row and check the value you are trying to pass in

Comment: the value getting is byte[] = 0x00009F960121136F

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192520/any-difference-between-parse-and-convert

Comment: What sort of value is contained in that byte[]? Is it really a UTF-8 encoded string representing a date literal?

Comment: it is coming like some symbols

Answer (score 0):

set cultureinfo to be sure, which format is used

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(yourCulture);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
```