# Insert Date from form to table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used AJAX CalendarExtender to TextBox control. I want the value (Date) from TextBox to my database table. How'd I used

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(..?..)
```

The value when I select from Calender is appearing as -

`August 9, 2012`

Comment: @RogerTaylor This is markup..
`<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender3" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="TextBox3"
        Format="MMMM d, yyyy">
        </asp:CalendarExtender>`

Answer (score 0):

HAve you tried to parse string with date time value like

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("August 9, 2012", "MMMM d, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateParameterName", date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest utilizing `DateTime.TryParse()`, cause user can enter any value into your text box, even invalid. `DateTime.ParseExact()` is appropriate only if you are sure that string is a valid datetime of exact format.
You can reader more about it and about `System.Convert.ToDateTime()` method here

[Any difference between DateTime.Parse and Convert.ToDateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192520/any-difference-between-parse-and-convert)