# From & To Date Filter on List Using LINQ working on Localhost but on IIS does not works

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, iis

(MVC.NET) Applied Date Filter on a list of`From` and `To` Date . It works fine on localhost but on publishing on IIS it does not works.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDate))
{
     candidateList = candidateList.FindAll(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.CandidateRegistrationDate).Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate).Date);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(toDate))
{
    candidateList = candidateList.FindAll(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.CandidateRegistrationDate).Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(toDate).Date);
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Check the dateformats on your server vs date formats on your local machine. Without the actual exception i would guess that your `Convert.ToDateTime` is failing.

Comment: I am getting this Exception in logs : _String was not recognized as a valid DateTime_

Comment: Used **_Datetime.Parse_** instead of _Convert.ToDateTime_ and it worked on IIS .  Came across this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192520/any-difference-between-datetime-parse-and-convert-todatetime] @Nico   culture info was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First what type is candidateList? is it a db object or a collection. Assuming its a db object, you will have to change the date functions and use EF date functions. Also try to extract the convert.Datetime() function from the linq query

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDate))
            {
                var Frodate = Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate).Date;
                candidateList = candidateList.FindAll(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CandidateRegistrationDate).Date >= date);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(toDate))
            {
                var tdate = Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate).Date;
                candidateList = candidateList.FindAll(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CandidateRegistrationDate) <= tdate);
            }
```