# how to solve string was not recognized as a valid date time?

Tags: c#

I have a component in c# and I write the following code:

```cs
string SearchString = " and StartDate Between '" 
    + string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(calender_az.Text)) 
    + "' And '" + string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(calender_ta.Text)) 
    + "'";
```

and it works but it has error like this:

> string was not recognized as a valid date time?
>    calender_az is date picker

what should I do?

Comment: Your where filter would translate into `and StartDate Between 2010/01/01 and 2010/12/31` but notice it would not contain datetime delimiters.

Comment: Look at the debugger what are the values: ```calender_az.Text```, ```calender_az.Text``` and check whether they are correct DateTime format

Comment: What you really should do, if this produces a query that goes to the database, is 1) use parameters, avoiding both formatting issues and SQL injection at the same time and 2) use `>=` and `<`, not `BETWEEN`, which is an inclusive range and can easily miss rows that are right on the edge.

Comment: You a forcing a specific culture using Convert.ToDateTime, perhaps you should consider `DateTime.ParseExact` instead, check [DateTime.Parse vs Convert.ToDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192520/any-difference-between-datetime-parse-and-convert-todatetime)

Comment: This error is only relative to `Convert.ToDateTime`(not `string.Format` and not SQL where). You may need to check the user input before converting to date time (text can be empty or a non-valid date format).

Comment: If calender_az is a DateTimePicker or another control that can only have dates there would be no SQLi @JeroenMostert otherwise your warning is good

Comment: calender_az  is date picker

Comment: @bradbury9 is this a web app or desktop app? Cause for web apps date picker or not, anything can be submitted. And even if this is a desktop app, using parameters for SQL queries is always a better way to write your queries.

Comment: @trailmax not enough info to know in the question. Thats why I said "DateTimePicker or another control that can only have dates". If there would be aspnet related tags I would +1 on the SQLi

Comment: `calendar_az` is a `DatePicker`. Why convert it's text to a `DateTime` when you can just access the `SelectedDate` property?  `string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", calender_az.SelectedDate)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTime AZ = DateTime.ParseExact(calender_az.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: `calendar_az` is a DatePicker.  Why convert it's text to a `DateTime` when you can just access the `SelectedDate` property?  There is not need for calling `ParseExact`.

Comment: because I use Persian picker and SQL can't support Persian date and a I had to got varchar in SQL and it is text.