# Better use int.Parse or Convert.ToInt32

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Whats the main difference between int.Parse() and Convert.ToInt32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32)

I would like to know what are PRO and CONS of using Convert.ToInt32 VS int.Parse.

Here an example of syntax I am using:

```
            int myPageSize = Convert.ToInt32(uxPageSizeUsersSelector.SelectedValue);

            int myPageSize = int.Parse(uxPageSizeUsersSelector.SelectedValue);
```

I also found out these articles, maybe they can help for a discussion:

- http://dotnetperls.com/int-parse
- http://aspdotnethacker.blogspot.com/2010/04/difference-between-int32parsestring.html
- http://aspdotnethacker.blogspot.com/p/visual-studio-performance-wizard.html

Comment: Neither method isfaster than a custom int parse code, because in parse has to deal with spaces, - hyphones, new lines, etc.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Convert.ToInt32` is for dealing with any object that implements `IConvertible` and can be converted to an `int`. Also, `Convert.ToInt32` returns `0` for `null`, while `int.Parse` throws a `ArgumentNullException`.

`int.Parse` is specifically for dealing with strings.

As it turns out, the `string` type's `IConvertible` implementation merely uses `int.Parse` in its `ToInt32` method.

So effectively, if you call `Convert.ToIn32` on a `string`, you *are* calling `int.Parse`, just with slightly more overhead (a couple more method calls).

This is true for any conversion from `string` to some primitive type (they all call `Parse`). So if you're dealing with strongly-typed `string` objects (e.g., you're parsing a text file), I'd recommend `Parse`, simply because it's more direct.

Converting arbitrary objects (returned to you by some external library, for instance) is the scenario where I'd opt for using the `Convert` class.

Answer (score 17):

There's not much difference. Here's a quote found on msdn.

> Basically the Convert class makes it
>   easier to convert between all the base
>   types.
>
> The Convert.ToInt32(String,
>   IFormatProvider) underneath calls the
>   Int32.Parse. So the only difference is
>   that if a null string is passed to
>   Convert it returns 0, whereas
>   Int32.Parse throws an
>   ArgumentNullException.
>   [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/1ca53a60-e094-4073-ab33-27cca0bdbad4)

Answer (score 3):

I cannot answer based on performance, but my preferred method is always int.tryparse(mystring, out myint) as that gives a clean failure that you can test for in the program flow (rather than doing a try/catch).

Comment: This really depends on what you want to do. If you really need the parsing to succeed, or you know that it is a valid representation of a number, it's totally valid to use int.Parse. What would you do when the TryParse fails in such a case? You would just throw another exception.

Comment: In my use, *one* exception would be thrown, and that would be a meaningful exception to my application - in your usage, two or more exceptions would be thrown, the one or more thrown by the int.Parse and caught by you and the one you throw to add context to the errors passed back up.

Answer (score 2):

The Convert interface is a more general purpose one. The net result should be the same though.

Internally, it just calls int.Parse:

```
public static int ToInt32(String value) {
    if (value == null)
        return 0;
    return Int32.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Above code is from the reference source.