# asp.net c# int.Parse or Convert.toInt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the main difference between int.Parse() and Convert.ToInt32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32)

What is better to use `int.Parse` or `Convert.toInt`? which one is more error prone and performance vice good?

Comment: With **over 200 questions** you should really be aware of the auto-suggest that SO provides as you type your question title by now. Are you sure you couldn't find any similar questions? Because I found many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Convert.ToInt32()` underneath calls the `Int32.Parse`. So the only difference is that if a `null string` is passed to Convert it `returns 0`, whereas `Int32.Parse` throws an `ArgumentNullException`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the implementation of Converto.ToInt, according to Reflector :

```
public static int ToInt32(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse is specifically to parse strings and gives you more control over what format the string may be. Convert.ToInt will handle almost any type that can be converted in the first place. 
What is more error prone depends on your input and the variations you expect.
int.TryParse is robust in that it won't throw an exception, the pitfall is that it is easy to hide the parsing error. This choice depends on what you want to do? Do you want to provide feedback, have detailed parsing error info, use alternative / default values?

Answer (score 0):

more error prone int.TryParse :)