# what is the difference between Convert.ToInt16 or 32 or 64 and Int.Parse?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the main difference between int.Parse() and Convert.ToInt32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32)

Hi

I want to know what is the different between :

```
Convert.ToInt16 or Convert.ToInt32 or Convert.ToInt64
```

vs

```
Int.Parse
```

both of them are doing the same thing so just want to know what the different?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Convert.ToInt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) converts an *object* to an integer and returns 0 if the value was null.

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32("43"); // x = 43;
int x = Convert.ToInt32(null); // x = 0;
int x = Convert.ToInt32("abc"); // throws FormatException
```

[`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) convert a *string* to an integer and throws an exception if the value wasn't able to convert

```
int x = int.Parse("43"); // x = 43;
int x = int.Parse(null); // x throws an ArgumentNullException
int x = int.Parse("abc"); // throws an FormatException
```

Comment: I tried these examples (using .NET 4 and .NET 3.5) and `Convert.ToInt32("abc");` will throw a `System.FormatException` just like `int.Parse("abc");` does.  The only time that no exception is thrown is on `Convert.ToInt32(null);`

Comment: @Joshua Rodgers: Thanks a lot, I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToInt32` will return 0 if the input string is null.  `Int32.Parse` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Convert.To(s)` doesn't throw an exception when argument is null, but `Parse()` does.`Convert.To(s)` returns 0 when argument is null.
2. `Int.Parse()` and `Int.TryParse()` can only convert strings. `Convert.To(s)` can take any class that implements IConvertible.Hence, `Convert.To(s)` is probably a [wee bit slower](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2005/12/19/505702.aspx) than `Int.Parse()` because it has to ask its argument what it's type is.