# Problem with Sum in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net-to-c#

I've got a LINQ query in VB:

```
Dim ss = _someClassDataSource.Sum(Function(s) TryCast(s, SomeClass).BreakdownCover)
```

where `BreakdownCover`'s type is `string`. When I'm trying rewrite it in C#:

```
var ss = _someClassDataSource.Sum(s=>s.BreakdownCover);
```

I get the exception:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'
```

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: In general, translating from VB.NET to C# is *immensely* easier if you first make the VB.NET work with `Option Explicit On` and `Option Strict On`.

Comment: Then again if you knew to program with those on, you'd probably be using a type-safe language in the first place...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use Int.Parse, don't cast a string to an int

```
var ss=_someClassDataSource.Sum(s=>int.Parse(s.BreakdownCover));
```

If you're doing VB.NET then use

```
var ss=_someClassDataSource.Sum(s=>Integer.Parse(s.BreakdownCover));
```

Here is why you can't cast string to int:

> Because the explicit cast isn't implemented... ToString() is a general
>   method (implemented in System.Object) and if string would implement
>   the cast that would beg the question if all other classes need to
>   implement it too...

It would potentially be better to not use Convert.ToInt32() because Convert.ToInt32 will still return a value when the string is null while int.Parse will throw. You might get unexpected results with Convert.ToInt32. Also see this question [Whats the main difference between int.Parse() and Convert.ToInt32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32)

Of course, this is based on the context as @Andy has pointed out. If you are ok with NULL being treated as 0 then either method will work.

Comment: You could argue that it would be beneficial to use Convert.ToInt32 as a null string will be treated as 0 and not cause and exception and return a result. Which one is better really depends on the context of the problem. In either case it will blow up if the string is "abc".

Comment: @DustingDavis - no problem, ultimately the best solution would be to use a non nullable numeric field in the database in the first place ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly convert the string to an int:

```
var ss=_someClassDataSource.Sum(s=> Convert.ToInt32(s.BreakdownCover));
```

As pointed out by DustinDavis [Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) will return a 0 if the string is null. If you would rather an exception be thrown then Int32.Parse will be a better option. However if the field accepts nulls and if these should be treated as 0 then this will return the expected result.

Comment: I think in this case with Sum() it would be ok, but not if it were Avg(). But again, depends on context. Good point.