# Converting Char into int after read from a file

Tags: c#, file-io, char, int

I am reading from a text file and I have a value that is read from the text file that I want to store as an `int`. I am doing this in c#. For example I read in 4 from the file but as a `char` it is 4 but if I just cast it to an `int` it takes the value 52, I think. How do I take that char value 4 and store it as an `int` as a 4?

Answer (score 4):

**Convert your character to string** and then you can use [int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx), [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx), [Convert.Int32(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) to convert it to integer value.

```
char ch = '4';
int val = Convert.ToInt32(ch.ToString());

// using int.Parse
int val2 = int.Parse(ch.ToString());

//using int.TryParse
int val3;
if(int.TryParse(ch.ToString(), out val3))
{
}
```

Comment: sidenote, difference between parse/tryparse/convert is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to just subtract out the value of `'0'`:

```
char c = '4';
int i = (int)(c - '0');
```

Or you could go through `string` instead:

```
char c = '4';
int i = int.Parse(c.ToString());
```

---

Note that if you have a string instead of a char, just do:

```
string value = "4";
int i = int.Parse(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [**Convert.ToInt32(string)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx),

```
int res = Convert.ToInt32(yourcharvar.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) always because it catches the exceptions if any.(It has inbuilt trycatch block) 
In other words, it is *Safe*.

```
char foo = '4';
int bar;
if(int.TryParse(foo.ToString(), out bar))  //if converted returns TRUE else FALSE
   Console.WriteLine(bar);   //bar becomes 4
else
   Console.WriteLine("The conversion is not possible");
```