# Casting string to double, dot gets removed

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

While casting from string to double, the dot gets removed, eg. for 0.01 after casting to double it gives 1, or for 3.22 it gives 322.

Below is the Code I used.

In log file I get

Before Usage :- 0.01

After it Parse :- 1

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    XmlNodeType nType = reader.NodeType;
    if (nType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "DepartmentUser")
    {
        UserData user = new UserData();
        while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
        {
            if (reader.Name == "UserName")
            {
                user.UserName = Convert.ToString(reader.Value);
            }
            else if (reader.Name == "UserID")
            {
                user.UserGUID = Convert.ToString(reader.Value);
            }
            else if (reader.Name == "UserUsage")
            {
                Logger.TraceLog(LogLevel.Debug, string.Format("Before Usage :- {0}", reader.Value));
                //user.DiskUsage = Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value);
                user.UserUsage = double.Parse(reader.Value);
                Logger.TraceLog(LogLevel.Debug, string.Format("After it Parse :- {0}", user.UserUsage));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this due to Culture?

Comment: I don't know why it would do that but you could simply divide it by 100 after converting to get the original number. But the question did get my curiosity. so ill take a look if it's the same for me.

Comment: Definitely culture settings, you will most likely have the decimal separator set to a comma

Comment: Note that parsing and casting are different things. You're not *casting* to double at all.

Comment: @somnath okey i tried it out and i see why its doing it. it has to do a little with the culture as it seems to use a diffrent decimal seperator use comma instead and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks @Sayse for advice i will do like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is indeed a culture issue - your thread's current culture probably uses `.` as a grouping separator rather than a decimal separator. In fact, in some cultures your code would just fail with an exception. Here's an example demonstrating the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var german = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
        var english = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
        var text = "1.5";

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = german;
        Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(text) == 1.5); // False

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = english;
        Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(text) == 1.5); // True
    }
}
```

Given that you're converting the content of XML, I'd use [`XmlConvert.ToDouble`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.todouble) instead. That will "do the right thing" assuming that the XML follows the standard representation (which it appears to here).

In this case that will be equivalent to specifying the invariant culture when calling `double.Parse` (I believe) but I'd prefer the `XmlConvert` approach because:

- It's more "clearly correct" for the context
- It's a pattern you can apply to other types (e.g. `DateTime`)

Note that if you can possibly read the whole XML document in using LINQ to XML instead, you're likely to find that simpler - and then you can just cast the attribute to `double` instead. (`XmlReader` is a pain in the neck - I'd recommend only using it when you *really* have to due to document size... even then, you could load subtrees into LINQ to XML types.)

Comment: Thanks @Jon I have used like this  user.UserUsage = XmlConvert.ToDouble(reader.Value);     but it showing comma(,) instead of Dot(.) i.e 3.22 convert to 3,22

Comment: @Somnath: What do you mean by "it showing"? What's showing the value?  The log? Don't forget that the value itself (when parsed) is just a number. If you want to log in a particular culture, you should change your `string.Format` call to do so.

Comment: the result in the log file is Before Usage :- 3.22 and After it Parse :- 3,22.The default culture is en.US

Comment: @Somnath: I really don't think the default culture *is* en-US there. Log it: `Logger.TraceLog(LogLevel.Debug, string.Format("Culture: {0}", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));`. What *possible* `double` value would you expect to be formatted as `3,22` in the US culture?

Comment: i log it as  Logger.TraceLog(LogLevel.Debug, string.Format("Current Culture :- {0},After it Parse :- {1}", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, user.DiskUsage)),
in log file 
Current Culture :- en.US,After it Parse :- 3,22
i want to format it as 3.22 in US.

Comment: @Somnath: That's `CurrentUICulture`, which isn't the same thing. Use `CurrentCulture`, as I suggested before. (`CurrentUICulture` is used for looking up resources; `CurrentCulture` is used for format patterns etc, as I understand it.)

Comment: now i get like this Current Culture :- nl-BE,After it Parse :- 3,63

Comment: @Somnath: So there you are. `nl-BE` (Belgium) is the culture being used to parse and format numbers. You asked how to fix the parsing - I've shown that. To fix the logging, pass in the culture you want to log in...

Answer (score 3):

You could try, this would make the result culture-insensitive.

```
double.Parse(reader.Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @Coline i used it,but it showing comma(,) instead of Dot(.) i.e 3.22 convert to 3,22

Answer (score -1):

Try using Convert.ToDouble instead

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "Using the ToDouble(String) method is equivalent to passing value to the Double.Parse(String) method. value is interpreted by using the formatting conventions of the current thread culture."

Comment: As I understood they were different. Have a look at this post for int.parse vs ToInt32 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32. I haven't spent a lot of time stying this though.

Comment: There are differences if you have a value of type `object` instead of `string`, and if the value is `null`. Those differences aren't relevant here.

Answer (score -2):

To parse your string to a double you need to use [conver.ToDouble()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Regards!

Comment: Why would the OP "need" to use that rather than `double.Parse`? And why do you think it would behave any differently, given the remarks of the documentation you linked to?