# datagridview cell null value error

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

If the value in datagridview cell is not entered the only way to handle the error is this for now. Anyone have better solution ?

```
Dim senderGrid = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

If TypeOf senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewButtonColumn _
        AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 _ 
        AndAlso senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Add" Then

    Dim _status As Integer

    Try
        _status = Math.Abs(CInt(dgv6.Item("dgv6_Aktivno", dgv6.CurrentRow.Index).Value))
    Catch ex As Exception
        _status = 0
    End Try

    Dim _id As Integer
    Try
        _id = dgv6.Item("dgv6_id", dgv6.CurrentRow.Index).Value
    Catch ex As Exception
        _id = 0
    End Try

End if
```

Comment: @Vivek.S So you want to say if the value is null or nothing then write default value ?

Comment: When this function is calling (_which event_)??

Comment: @Vivek.S dgv6_CellContentClick

Comment: IF ELSE is a good idea  than Try Catch

Answer (score 0):

As you are converting a value to `Integer` and setting `0` as its default value, you can try `Convert.ToInt32` to handle `null` values but with some precautions. `Convert.ToInt32` converts any `null` values as `0`

```
_status = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32("VALUE_TO_CONVERT"))
```

And the **precautions:**

1. `VALUE_TO_CONVERT` must of type `String`.
2. You may still need to handle the cases where `VALUE_TO_CONVERT` contains any symbols like `,`, `.`, `()` or chars.
3. You also need to take care if `VALUE_TO_CONVERT` is of type `Char`

For details discussion on conversions check [whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32) and also the [MSDN for Convert.ToInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx)