# What is the difference between Convert.ToInt32 and (int) Parsing

Tags: c#, console, int, double

I can't understand the difference between `Convert.ToInt32` and Parsing (int) command when i convert a double number to a int number.My example code is here and i have two different answer when i show it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double i = 3.897456465;
        int y;
        y = Convert.ToInt32(i);
        Console.WriteLine(y);
        y = (int)i;
        Console.WriteLine(y);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what are the answers you get, and what did the documentation show you when you looked at it?

Comment: i get "4" when i use Convert.ToInt32 and "3" when i use parsing.

Comment: some reading. doesnt use doubles but gives an explanation of what happens behind the scenes  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32

Answer (score 4):

`(int) i;`  is casting not parsing.

[`Convert.ToInt32(double)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz(v=vs.110).aspx) would round the number to nearest 32 bit integer. Whereas casting `(int) i;` would only take the integer part of the double value and assign it to the variable.

Since one does rounding and the other just take the integer value, you see the difference.

Consider the following example:

```
double d = 1.99d;
int castedValue = (int) d; //1
int convertedValue = Convert.ToInt32(d); //2
```

In the above code, casting returned `1` since that is the integer part of the double value, whereas the conversion using `Convert.ToInt32` rounded the value.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation from `Convert.ToInt32(double)`:

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Int32
>   `value`, rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If `value` is halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.

From the C# 5 specification section 6.2.1, explicit numeric conversions:

> For a conversion from float or double to an integral type [...]
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, the source operand is **rounded towards zero** to the nearest integral value. If this integral value is within the range of the destination type then this value is the result of the conversion.

(Emphasis mine.)

So basically, `Convert.ToInt32` rounds up or down to the nearest `int`. Casting always rounds towards zero.