# How can I split a string like "12-15" into two numbers?

Tags: c#, string, split

My front-end application sends strings that look like this:

```
"12-15"
```

to a back-end C# application.

Can someone give me some pointers as to how I could extract the two numbers into two variables. Note the format is always the same with two numbers and a hyphen between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string into parts:

```
string s = "12-15";
string[] num = s.Split('-');
int part1 = Convert.ToInt32(num[0]);
int part2 = Convert.ToInt32(num[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 string stringToSplit = "12-15";
 string[] splitStringArray;
 splitStringArray = stringToSplit.Split('-');
```

splitStringArray[0] will be 12

splitStringArray[1] will be 15

Comment: I need to get the numbers 12 and 15 to be int.  Can I just cast these to int or should I use something else?

Comment: int.TryParse(string, out intVariable)

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] numbers = "12-15".Split('-')
        .Select(x => {
            int n;
            int.TryParse(x, out n);
            return n;
        })
        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

We call Split on a string instance. This program splits on a single character

```
string s ="12-15";
string[] words = s.Split('-');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    int convertedvalue = Convert.ToInt32(word ); 
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}

string[] ss= s.Split('-');
int x = Convert.ToInt32(ss[0]);
int y = Convert.ToInt32(ss[1]);
```

[more info](https://www.dotnetperls.com/split)

Comment: How can I make the strings as ints?

Comment: once you split you will get those values inside loop then you can convert to int using dot net conversion helpers

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct version without the wrong code

```
string textReceived = "12-15";

string[] numbers = textReceived.Split('-');
List<int> numberCollection = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in numbers)
{
    numberCollection.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item));
}
```

Comment: won't the split return strings?

Comment: Look at the revised code this will give a nice int list to work with.

Comment: The code you wrote in the first three examples does not even compile... The return type of String.Split is string[], not int[].

Comment: @jeroenh you are correct I just wasnt sure if you are supposed to leave your code before your revisions or not i will take them off now

Comment: @Nick the goal is for future readers to have a clear answer. You can always consult the history of changes if needed.

Comment: @jeroenh thank you for the information I will follow those guidelines from now on

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to split and it will return string for each value, then you can typecast it to any type you wish to ...

```
string myString = "12-15-18-20-25-60";
string[] splittedStrings = myString.Split('-');
foreach (var splittedString in splittedStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(splittedString + "\n");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String numberString = "12-15" ;
string[] arr = numberString.Split("-");
```

Now you will get  a string array , you can use parsing to get the numbers alone

```
int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(arr[0]);
```

Helpful answer related to parsing :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/199484/5395773

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = null;
string[] strArr = null;
int count = 0;
str = "12-15";
char[] splitchar = { '-' };

strArr = str.Split(splitchar);
for (count = 0; count <= strArr.Length - 1; count++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(strArr[count]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert that string explicitly to an integer array using `Array.ConvertAll` method and access the numbers using their index, you can run the below example [here](http://rextester.com/MCO27673).

```
using System;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var number = "12-15";
            var numbers = Array.ConvertAll(number.Split('-'), int.Parse);
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can explicitly convert the numeric string using `int.Parse` method, the int keyword is an alias name for `System.Int32` and it is preffered over the complete system type name `System.Int32`, you can run the below example [here](http://rextester.com/BKQ78163).

```
using System;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var number = "12-15";
            var numbers = number.Split('-');
            var one = int.Parse(numbers[0]);
            var two = int.Parse(numbers[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(one);
            Console.WriteLine(two);
        }
    }
}
```

Additional read: Please check [`int.Parse` vs. `Convert.Int32` vs. `int.TryParse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32) for more insight on parsing the input to integer