# What is the difference between converting and parsing of types in c#

Tags: c#, types, casting, type-conversion

What is the difference between doing something like `DateTime.Parse()` and `Convert.ToDateTime()` they both produce the same result but is there any advantage of one over the other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the main difference between int.Parse() and Convert.ToInt32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime(v=vs.110).aspx  should be pretty accurate

Comment: Well, to be fair, it's probably best to avoid both. 99 times out of 100, you only need to convert a string to date, and for that, `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` are the best options.

Answer (score 0):

this sample maybe help you :

int.Parse(string s) :
Simply, int.Parse (string s) method converts the string to integer. If string s is null, then it will throw ArgumentNullException. If string s is other than integer value, then it will throw FormatException. If string s represents out of integer ranges, then it will throw OverflowException.

Convert.ToInt32(string s) :
Simply, Convert.ToInt32(string s) method converts the string to integer. If string s is null, then it will return 0 rather than throw ArgumentNullException. If string s is other than integer value, then it will throw FormatException. If string s represents out of integer ranges, then it will throw OverflowException.

[article link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/845439/Difference-between-int-Parse-Convert-ToInt-and-int)