# Do I have to try catch the individual function or can i wrap it around a larger block?

Tags: c#, exception

The .Replace() is causing the exception because authorElement.QuerySelector(...).InnerTextClean is returning null. This is very rare (1/100,000) so I would rather use try catch than check for null.

```
author.salescount = Convert.ToInt32(authorElement.QuerySelector("div.sale-info.is-hidden-phone > em").InnerTextClean.Replace(",", ""));
```

So my question is, do I have to break this up into many lines and only try catch the individual function that fails?

.ToInt32() obviously cant accept a null, but I would assume the try catch block will throw the exception as soon as it occurs. So then I could wrap the entire thing.

I guess I solved it, am I wrong and/or is there something I haven't considered?

Comment: `I would rather use try catch than check for null.` That is the wrong decision. Use `int.TryParse`.

Comment: Perfect, that's why I posted this.

Comment: Checking for null is better than handling NullReferenceException... Check the output of `authorElement.QuerySelector` for null before trying to convert it to integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the main difference between int.Parse() and Convert.ToInt32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32)

Comment: According to MSDN : Check for error conditions in code if the event happens routinely and could be considered part of normal execution. When you check for common error conditions, less code is executed because you avoid exceptions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions

Comment: From the same article. `For conditions that are likely to occur but might trigger an exception, consider handling them in a way that will avoid the exception` Which seems pertinent to your situation. :) In terms of proving to you that the approach I am suggesting is superior to yours - I can't. I mean, mine is likely easier to read and may perform faster. But, if you want to do it your way no-one is going to stop you.

Comment: Ahh ok, I understand now. It would be interesting to see what actually happens when a try catch is executed -- like memory flows and in whatever language C# is written in (C++?)... maybe I'll do some research and make another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle the null case instead of `try`/`catch`

```
string inner = authorElement.QuerySelector("div.sale-info.is-hidden-phone > em")?.InnerTextClean?.Replace(",", "");
int temp;
author.salescount = int.TryParse(inner, out temp) ? temp : -1; // -1 in case of null
```