# What is the correct way to take input in c#, Convert vs Parse

Tags: c#, variables

I saw some other ways to take input from user in c# and it's really confusing.
*Can I use both the way to take input or is it only for float*?

Is there more ways to take input?

```
float myAge;

myAge = Convert.Toint64(Console.ReadLine());
```

vs

```
float myAge;

float myAge = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Better still: `float.TryParse`. Never assume that input from a user is in the correct format

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend `TryParse`, to avoid exceptions in case user does not provide a valid float.

```
float myAge;
float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out myAge);
```

or in 1 line `float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out float myAge);`

`TryParse` will return a bool you can use to check if the value is a valid float.

```
if(float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out myAge)){
   //do stuff
}else{
    Console.WriteLine("You did not give a float");
}
```

`double`, `int` have these methods too. Its not only for `floats`.

Answer (score 0):

```
myAge = Convert.Toint64(Console.ReadLine())
```

Above will throw an exception when you enter a fraction as your input. Convert will attempt to converted to a 64bit integer and then get assigned to your variable myAge which is a float. If it is a fraction conversion will fail and throw exception.

```
float myAge = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Above, with using float.Parse will retain the floating point number with fractions. However, will throw exception if it is non numeric.

Best option is to use TryPrase and confirm if entry is good:

```
float myAge;
while(!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out myAge))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry, enter a number.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated what the desired data type is: `float`, `Int64` (`long`), or something else?  Seeing as how `myAge` is a `float` in both snippets that suggests you want the user to be able to input a `float`, so you should use a method that returns a `float`.

You could certainly read a `long` and store it in a `float`, but I don't see any reason to do that.  Why let your variable store a fractional part if you won't let the user actually input one?  If you read a `long`, store it in a `long`.  If you store a `float`, call a method that reads a `float`.

Note that you are comparing `Convert.ToInt64()` to `float.Parse()`, when it seems like you should be comparing...

- `Convert.ToInt64()` to `Convert.ToSingle()` (`float` being an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/built-in-types-table) for `Single`), and...
- `float.Parse()` to `long.Parse()`

As others have mentioned, there are also `TryParse()` versions of the `Parse()` methods.

It all really comes down to personal preference.  To me, *parsing* is the specific operation being performed, so I would choose a `Parse()` (or `TryParse()`) method.  Some people might prefer the more general `Convert.ToXXX()` methods since they have overloads for many more datatypes beyond just `string`.  In the end, [`Convert.ToInt64()` is internally calling `Int64.Parse()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1320), anyways...

```
public static long ToInt64(string value) {
    if (value == null)
        return 0;
    return Int64.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

...and is [documented as such](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint64#System_Convert_ToInt64_System_String_)...

> Using the [ToInt64(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint64#System_Convert_ToInt64_System_String_) method is equivalent to passing `value` to the [Int64.Parse(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int64.parse#System_Int64_Parse_System_String_) method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the response exists here : [**Difference between int.Parse() and Convert.ToInt32**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32/201405)