# Relational Operator Statement And Output Don't Seem To Match

Tags: c#, relational-operators

Good day all, I'm new to C# and currently at the stage of experimenting with if-else statements. Upon declaring variables **ageUser**, **permittedAge**, **input** and running the program, I noticed that the if statement and the resulting output don't seem to match.

```
        int ageUser;
        int permittedAge = 18;
        int input;

        Console.Write("Put in your age: ");
        input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
        ageUser = input;

        if (ageUser < permittedAge)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you are not permitted to enter this site!");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
        }
```

[Link To Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPLnO.png)

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());` should be `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`. You should have spotted the wrong result when debugging the value of `ageUser`

Comment: Hello Danny. I think that you must use Console.ReadLine instead of Console.Read. Console.Read read only one character.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-ClaudeColette for the clarification.

Comment: @UnholySheep If I may ask, when is it appropriate to use `Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());` and `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`?

Comment: I can't think of any case where `Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());` would be the right thing to use, but there's probably some use case. In most cases you want to read user input using `Console.ReadLine()` (and `int.Parse` vs `Convert.ToInt32` is a different discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change how you read in the input. Read() reads in a character and does not convert that to int like you think it does. (5 becomes 53 due to its ASCII representation). Use `ReadLine` instead.

Use the folowing instead.

```
    Console.Write("Put in your age: ");
    input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    ageUser = input;
```